# Bar chart using raphaël

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I like to bring a chart as shown

[image]

By using rapheal. Its very tough for me to learn it. show me some live example with code to draw verticalbar graph.

My data values

x-axis {1,2,3,4,5} This is an id of question
y-axis {10,20,30,40,7} This represent number of visits of question

I need bar graph with x,y values in plot and label for each axis and for graph

Comment: Could I suggest that you post the mark-up you want to convert *into* a graph? That way you might get something directly useful that you can *also* learn from.

Comment: i am not able to see your chart:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic implementation would be:

```
var r = Raphael("holder"),
    data = [[10], [105], [30]];

r.g.barchart(0, 0, width, height, data);
```

Then you can manipulate it with raphael.js.

Note. g.raphael can be found here: http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Tutorial is very tough for me. but i like to use rapheal. I need bar graph

Comment: umm... g.raphael, does use raphael, hence the name... =)